# Unity with Firebase freezes after compile (AssetDatabase.Refresh)

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

After adding functionality to Listen to Firestore database updates, my Unity-Firebase app crashes whenever the AssetDatabase Refreshes. Looking in the error log I see

`0x00007FFD2F8F6D06 (FirebaseCppApp-6_16_1) SWIGRegisterStringCallback_StorageInternal`

And some other Firebase access errors. This only happens after adding ListenerRegistration to firestore documents, even though the listener registration is being .Dispose()d.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this to SO because it took me many days to solve this problem and found no helpful information addressing one fundamental problem source: The [Unity Getting Started Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) never inform you to use FirebaseApp.Dispose()

My solution was simple, though discovering it was not:

```
// During initialization:
firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

// Clean up when quitting app
    private void OnApplicationQuit() {
        listenerRegistration.Dispose();  // Any event listener must be disposed
        firebaseApp.Dispose();  // the base firebase app must be disposed
    }
```

Comment: If y'all haven't already, would you mind filing this as a bug at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues ? I can do it on your behalf, but it would be easier if the team could communicate directly if needed. You should _not_ have to call .Dispose on Firebase under normal workflows, and the team may want to look at this like a bug. Feel free to refer them to this comment or tag me (@patm1987) on GitHub if you do.

Comment: @PatrickMartin Will do. Thank you for all your wonderful work on Firebase <3